# Get redirected to a div automatically without user's intervention

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am new to JavaScript.

The problem goes as follows: 
I have 10 `div` in my `html` file. I  am using links to go from one to another. Now, I want to test a condition which if satisfied (I am using `python` for this), should redirect me to another `div` within the same html. But I want that to be automatic. For eg, I am in `<div id="table1">` and inside it I am checking a condition. If that is true, I should be redirected automatically to `<div id="table3">`.
Can anyone please help me find the way out?
On google,when I am trying to search for it, it is giving me results where I have to click a button for redirection (which will invoke a `JS` function). But I don't want that. I want it to happen automatically. So, please tell.

`<div id="table5">
    <div  style="position:fixed;right:40px;top:65px;">
        <a name="t10" href="#t10" onclick='show(10);'><button>  GO TO MAIN PAGE  </button></a>
    </div>
    % if not obj.i:
        <h2>REDIRECT ME TO id="table3"</h2>
    % else:
        <table border=1 cellpadding=7>
            <tr>
                <th>Row No. in Sheet</th>
                <th>Parameters</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2>Total : ${value}</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    % endif
</div>`

Comment: and inside it I am checking a condition...What do you mean?

Comment: added code to the post:)

Comment: You can not check any conditions using a _server-side_ language dynamically on the _client_.

Comment: This is just a snippet of entire thing. I am perfectly able to do this condition check, but want a solution for automatic redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to search the code for you. But most sites tell you you need an onclick event because that is needed to open a link. And example.com`#idOfDiv`, is the kind of link you would open. Howerver, there is another possibility.

Find some javascript code to decide the position of an element in `x and y coordinats`. After you got it, make `JS Scroll` ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="table5">
    <div  style="position:fixed;right:40px;top:65px;">
        <a name="t10" href="#t10" onclick='show(10);'><button>  GO TO MAIN PAGE  </button></a>
    </div>
    % if not obj.i:
        <script>window.location="#table6"</script> // redirect
    % else:
        <table border=1 cellpadding=7>
            <tr>
                <th>Row No. in Sheet</th>
                <th>Parameters</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan=2>Total : ${value}</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    % endif
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. I am actually busy in some other task. When I am done, I will check that thoroughly and will tell. Ok?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not replying soo late. Actually its not working the way I want. I did what you told, but its not working :(